# How to register a decorator with Autofac: "Circular component dependency detected"

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I have got a Circular dependency to extend the functionality of an object adding a cache abstraction.

```
 public class CachedDecorator : IParameter
{
    public CachedDecorator (IParameter decorated);
    ...
}


 public class MyImplementationParameter : IParameter
 {
   ...
 }
```

Using .Net core Dependency injection container i can do something like this to create those dependencies and it works:

```
services.AddSingleton<IParameter>(provider => new CachedDecorator 
(provider.GetRequiredService<MyImplementationParameter >()));
```

How Can I replicate that declaration using Autofac?

I am trying something like this:

```
   builder.RegisterType<CachedDecorator>()
  .As<IParameter>()
  .WithParameter(
    new ResolvedParameter(
      (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(MyImplementationParameter ),
      (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<MyImplementationParameter>()));
```

But i get a "Circular component dependency detected: "

Comment: I'd guess the ResolvedParameter condition needs to be typeof(IParameter), not typeof(MyImplementationParameter)

Answer (score 0):

As of Autofac 4.9, you can register your decorator as follows:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MyImplementationParameter>().As<IParameter>();
builder.RegisterDecorator<CachedDecorator, IParameter>();
```

See [the documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/v4.9.4/advanced/adapters-decorators.html) for more information.

Comment: It doesn't recognize RegisterDecorator: "container builder doesn't contain a definition for register decorator " and not accessible extension method RegisterDecorator accepting a first argument of type container builder could be found